# ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: username>": "MessageModel.user_name" must be a "Room" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I have ita MessageModel which have a field user_name which is a instance of Room model. i want to save all the messages of current user inline but when i try to save username which is instance of Room model...an error occured like--> ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: username>": "MessageModel.user_name" must be a "Room" instance.
I have a another model DateTimeField which has the following field datecreated and date_modified.

models.py-->

```
class Room(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner', null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
class MessageModel(DateTimeModel):
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(Room, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name = 'sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    message = models.TextField('body')
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='recipients')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
```

forms.py-->

```
class MessageModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MessageModel
class RoomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MessageModelInline]
admin.site.register(Room, RoomAdmin)
```

```
@database_sync_to_async
def save_message_to_db(self,username, message):
    user_name = self.user_name
    print(type(user_name))     # <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>

    return MessageModel.objects.create(user_name=user_name, user=username, message=message)
```

any solution will be highly appreciated. ThankYou

Comment: user_name in MessageModel should be an instance of Room model

Comment: user_name in MessageModel is ForeignKey of Room model. isn't it the instance of Room?

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageModel.objects.create(user_name=user_name, user=username, message=message)
```

The above line should be changed to something like this line below

```
MessageModel.objects.create(user_name=instance_of_Room, user=username, message=message)
```